# Can I trust react-devtools not to breach my privacy?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, security, privacy

I am starting to develop webapps in React, and I have found out that the Chrome extension react-devtools is almost a defacto requirement for coding react applications.

The tool (and react) is made by Facebook, a company infamously known for their complete lack of moral when it comes to data gathering and creepy surveilance of us all. And it requires the ability to access everything you are browsing (which is probably needed to work it's magic), in order to be installed.

react-devtools have almost 1,5 million users (and they are probably all developers). Am I supposed to believe that Facebook will not exploit this obvious opportunity to follow every single thing we developers do in Chrome?

Does anybody in here know anything about react-devtools, and have anybody tried to analyse what data react-devtools sends in what directions? Because frankly I don't have this amount of trust for Facebook anymore, but is seems like react-devtools is inevitable, if I want to make React apps? :-(

Comment: FB isn't open-source tool. React devtools are. You can audit the code if you have no trust in OS community, https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools . If you're concerned with devtools, why not question React too?

Comment: That is a good and valid point! I myself have insufficient skills for doing a trustworthy audit, but I guess someone in the opensource community would have found breaches in the code, if they were there? :-)

Comment: ...and thanks for the downvotes anonymous angry guys - I have tried to google this, but haven't found anything at all - I couldn't even find a Terms of Usage on react-devtools - only see that it asks for access to all my browsing, so I really didn't know where to go to with my concern, for a qualified security take on it. :(

Comment: *I guess someone in the opensource community would have found breaches in the code, if they were there* - this is applicable to any OS product. If there were known security problems, they would certainly be addressed by the community. As for privacy breaches, this concern seems to be farfetched (not impossible, but Facebook argument doesn't make the scenario more probable). *I have tried to google this, but haven't found anything at all* -  I didn't downvote, but the whole idea about FB infiltrating OS tool seems a bit paranoid. If there are things to suspect, React looks more tempting.

Comment: Btw, privacy concerns for dev tools are not not entirely baseless. E.g. AngularJS provides error reports that lead to their website, like https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20Module%20 . I doubt that Google can extract any usable data from this request. Still, it provides them with some data about the implementation that wouldn't be available for them otherwise.

Comment: @estus please dump your first comment as an answer, so I can accept it, and close this thread! :-)

Comment: I didn't think this was an unreasonable or paranoid question. At worst it's a newbie question, which stackoverflow should support. I got here by googling for similar information, so it's useful to me that it's been asked. The extension does ask for permission to see your data on all websites, and it's not obvious to me as naive user of Chrome extensions that the code on github is guaranteed identical to what actually gets installed (i.e. that the OSS community can inspect installed code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook isn't open-source tool but React devtools are. They have the same chances to contain malicious code that infringes on user's privacy as React itself. The probability for such code to exist is negligible due to the attention from open-source community but it exists.

You can audit the code if you have no trust in OS community, https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools .

There are existing cases like AngularJS error reporting, an error is given as URL and supposed to be viewed on official website, e.g. https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20Module%20 . It allows a company (Google) to collect anonymous data about application implementation details. Errors don't necessarily contain sensitive or usable data that affect privacy in any way but they potentially can.